# How can I pull open a file by most recent fiscal month?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of code to open up a workbook based on a `dt` string that I specify.

```
Const filename = "Labor_Data_"
Const basepath = "C:\Users\CDL File"
Dim wbPreviousData as workbook
Dim dt As String: dt = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now), "mm_yyyy")
```

and then I open up the previous months file with:

`Set wbPreviousData = Workbooks.Open(basepath & "\" & filename & dt & ".xlsx")`

But I realize that my company's fiscal calendar can sometimes span 5 weeks, e.g. (last week of March - to - first week of May)

Is there an easy way to update my code to just reference the most recent month that is saved in a file pathway that I specify?

Comment: The only way I was able to solve this same problem was to create a table (on a hidden worksheet) with start and end dates (and number of labor hours per month) for my company's fiscal calendar. Then I created a set of functions that, given a calendar date, would tell me in which fiscal month that date falls. Each year I have to update the internal calendar to match the fiscal calendar published by Finance.

Comment: If you want to open last created file than get the files dates using function `FileDateTime ("C:\Documents\MyFile.xlsx")` and pick the most recent.

Comment: @Vlado So, this should work, and I attempted it like: `Dim LResult as Date` and then `LResult = FileDateTime("C:\...\CDL*.xlsx")` and then `workbooks.open LResult`, but then it gives me a run-time 52 bad file name error?

Comment: As the function name says it returns the date when the file was created. You need to read this way all files in directory and open the most recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to scan all the files in the directory to find the latest

```vb
Sub findlatest()

    Const filename = "Labor_Data_"
    Const basepath = "C:\Users\CDL File"

    Dim file As String, absfile As String
    Dim latest As String, ts As Double, tsmax As Double

    file = Dir(basepath & "\" & filename * "*")
    Do While Len(file) > 0

       ' check timestamp
       absfile = basepath & "\" & file
       ts = CDbl(FileDateTime(absfile))

       If ts > tsmax Then
          tsmax = ts
          latest = file
       End If

       file = Dir
    Loop

    Debug.Print latest

End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up finding something very similar, but this also works. Thank you!